# Blender to Unity 5: Using more than 1 rig with animations

Tags: rigging, unity

I have a model that is rigged and also a weapon that is rigged. The rig of the weapon is connected to the model's hand so that it moves accordingly (I connected it with CNTRL+P > Set parent to bone). I then made the animations for the model and then the bow and combined them using the NLA editor. The problem is, when I use the .blend file in Unity 5, the weapon doesn't move, only the model. Am I joining the two incorrectly or am I just using the NLA editor wrong? Thanks.

Edit: I don't actually save anything in the NLA editor because I assumed you didn't have to (and I don't see any save button xD). I'm very confused as to how I'm supposed to get whatever I just made in the NLA editor into something I can use in Unity.

Comment: I don't think the NLA strips do get exported to unity, only the Actions do get exported (keyframe animations)..

Comment: @Jerryno Okay, so then if I want to move both my model and weapon in the same animation I need to combine the rig or something?

Comment: Yes that's one way it would work, but then you can't swap weapons - it would be one skinned mesh with one armature. You can export both models separately with own animations and synchronize them in engine.

Comment: @Jerryno I see. Well I only need one weapon for this purpose as it's the first time I'm actually making stuff in blender. Thanks, I'll try that out.